# How to sum $a_n$ from 1 to infinity?

Tags: summation

Where $a_n =  (1 - a_{n-1})(.1)$ when n is even, $= (1 - a_{n-1})(.2)$ when n is odd and $a_1 = .3$. Thank you.

Comment: Do you think $a_n\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$? I don't think it does, which would make $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ diverge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When $n$ is even you have

$$\begin{align*}
a_n&=(1-a_{n-1})(0.1)\\
&=\big(1-(1-a_{n-2})(0.2)\big)(0.1)\\
&=(1-0.2+0.2a_{n-2})(0.1)\\
&=(0.8+0.2a_{n-2})(0.1)\\
&=0.08+0.02a_{n-2}\;,
\end{align*}$$

and when $n$ is odd you have

$$\begin{align*}
a_n&=(1-a_{n-1})(0.2)\\
&=\big(1-(1-a_{n-2})(0.1)\big)(0.2)\\
&=(1-0.1+0.1a_{n-2})(0.2)\\
&=(0.9+0.1a_{n-2})(0.2)\\
&=0.18+0.02a_{n-2}\;.
\end{align*}$$

It’s not hard to check that all terms are positive, so these results show that $a_n\ge0.08$ for each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$, and therefore $\sum_{n\ge 1}a_n$ diverges.

Answer (score 1):

we must have $lim ^{a_n}_{n \to \infty}=0$

suppose $lim ^{a_n}_{n \to \infty}=l $

for even n we have
 $a_n=(1-a_{n-1})(.1)$ so

$lim ^{a_n}_{n \to \infty}=lim^{(1-a_{n-1})(.1)}_{n \to \infty}$ so

$10l=1-l \to l=\frac{1}{11}$

then sumation is not convergence

Comment: May I know more about this method? How do you know the limit of a_n exists?

Comment: frist suppose that summation is convergence then we will have contradiction becuase if summation is convergence then we must have lim a_n exist and equal 0 but you can see at the bove it will not happend (lim a_n=0 will not happend)

Comment: Why the only case of convergence is $a_n \to 0$? AND Why the limit of $a_n$ is contradicted when you can find it's limit $l$?